# How to disable choose file in PrimeNg

Tags: primeng

```
 <p-fileUpload mode="basic" [disabled]="true" name="demo[]" url="./upload.php" accept="application/x-pem-file" (onSelect)="myUploader($event, i)" maxFileSize="1000000"></p-fileUpload>
```

Here disabled is not working as expected, it needs to restrict user click event action

Comment: Does it opening the file chooser window. ?

Comment: It would be easy if you provide stackblitz that reproduce the issue.

Comment: Yeah it is opening the file chooser window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a very basic version of file chooser demo for primeng with disabled property, and Its working fine.

[working code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-dropdowns-bug-bg8pk9)

Comment: Yeah, it works fine, I have client created PrimeNg template I think there is the issue, Thank you for your response